# How do add <legend> to a backbone form? Where in the schema does it go?

Tags: backbone.js, label, legend, backbone-relational, backbone-forms

```
Scout.models.Equipment = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  schema:{
    asset_number:{ type:'Text' },
    notes: 'TextArea',
    tag:{ type: 'Text', validators: ['required']}
  },
  defaults: {
    id: null,
    name: null,
  }
});
```

I want to add a legend to the scheme but the examples dont have a legend.

Answer (score 1):

While the main examples do not have any, There is some in the code

[Here](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms/blob/6535ad06b6e751274dfe601c95b44c4c82c8dd6c/test/index.html#L147)

For example

It is working in the page if you view it (it will run tests as well)